Configure libvirt VPN to connect through WireGuard VPN through the host without the host being on the VPN
Here is my system configuration:

Debian stable + KDE
virt-manager
2x VMs using bridge network so they get an IP on my LAN and the rest of my network can see them

I want to create 2+ more VMs that connect through a WireGuard VPN (provided by NordVPN) but I also want these VMs to be devices on my LAN so the rest of my network can see the VM (even though it can't access the host). And I don't want my host or some VMs to go through the VPN.
I was able to create a WireGuard VPN in Network Manager on the host but then the host also uses the VPN. (guide, guide, guide, guide).
Is it possible to have it so some VMs go through the WireGuard VPN but not the host or other VMs?
And, for my use case, I need the VPN to be managed by the host, not the VM. I don't want to have to install VPN stuff on the VM to get it to connect. I want the host to manage it so guests automatically get the VPN.
